Completion of a category $\mathcal{A}$ that is relatively concrete over a category $\mathcal{B}$
Preliminaries
Let $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be a faithful functor between categories. This turns $\mathcal{A}$ into a relatively concrete category over $\mathcal{B}$ (for example, take $\mathcal{B} = \mathsf{Set}$). Say that a morphism $b: F(A_1) \to F(A_2)$ comes from $\mathcal{A}$ if there exists a morphism $a: A_1 \to A_2$ with $F(a) = b$.
The category $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$
Now, define a new category $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$:

The objects of $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ are triples $(B, T_B, F_B)$ where $B$ is an object of $\mathcal{B}$, $T_B$ is a collection of morphisms $F(A_1) \to B$ and $F_B$ is a collection of morphisms $B \to F(A_2)$ (where $A_1$ and $A_2$ range over the objects of $\mathcal{A}$) with the following properties:

Let $A_2$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$ and $f: B \to F(A_2)$ a morphism. Then, $f \in F_B$ iff for all objects $A_1$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and morphisms $t \in T_B$, $t: F(A_1) \to B$, $f \circ t: F(A_1) \to F(A_2)$ comes from $\mathcal{A}$

Let $A_1$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$ and $t: F(A_1) \to B$ a morphism. Then, $t \in T_B$ iff for all objects $A_2$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and morphisms $f \in F_B$, $f: B \to F(A_2)$, $f \circ t: F(A_1) \to F(A_2)$ comes from $\mathcal{A}$



The morphisms of $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ between objects $(B_1, T_{B_1}, F_{B_1})$ and $(B_2, T_{B_2}, F_{B_2})$ are morphisms $b: B_1 \to B_2$ such that the following property is fulfilled:

For all $t \in T_{B_1}$, $t: F(A_1) \to B_1$ and $f \in F_{B_2}$, $f: B_2 \to F(A_2)$, $f \circ b \circ t: F(A_1) \to F(A_2)$ comes from $\mathcal{A}$



The functor $I: \mathcal{A} \to \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$
We obtain a functor $I: \mathcal{A} \to \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ in the following way:
Starting from an object $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$, define $I(A) = (F(A), T_{F(A)}, F_{F(A)})$, where $T_{F(A)}$ is the collection of all morphisms $t: F(A_1) \to F(A)$ which come from $\mathcal{A}$ and $F_{F(A)}$ is the collection of all morphisms $f: F(A) \to F(A_2)$ which come from $\mathcal{A}$. (Equivalently, we could say that $T_{F(A)}$ is the collection of all $F(t)$ for morphisms $t: A_1 \to A$ and $F_{F(A)}$ is the collection of all    $F(f)$ for morphisms $f: A \to A_2$.)
Now, to see that property (1.) and (2.) hold, taking any $t \in T_{F(A)}$ and $f \in F_{F(A)}$, both come from $\mathcal{A}$, so the composition $f \circ t$ also comes from $\mathcal{A}$. Conversely, if $f: F(A) \to F(A_2)$ is a morphism with $f \not\in F_{F(A)}$, then taking $\operatorname{id}: F(A) \to F(A)$, we have that $f \circ \operatorname{id} = f$ does not come from $\mathcal{A}$. Analogously, if $t: F(A_1) \to F(A)$ is a morphism with $t \not\in T_{F(A)}$, then taking $\operatorname{id}: F(A) \to F(A)$ we have that $\operatorname{id} \circ t = t$ does not come from $\mathcal{A}$.
Taking any morphism $a: A_1 \to A_2$, we set $I(a) = F(a)$. Take $t \in T_{F(A_1)}$ and $f \in F_{F(A_2)}$. Now, $f \circ I(a) \circ t$ is a composition of morphisms that come from $\mathcal{A}$, so it comes from $\mathcal{A}$. Hence $I(a): I(A_1) \to I(A_2)$ is a morphism.
The category $\widehat{(\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}})}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$
Additionally, $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ is also equipped with a faithful functor to $\mathcal{B}$ in a natural way: Define $G: \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}} \to \mathcal{B}, (B, T_B, F_b) \mapsto B$. In particular, we can form the category $\widehat{(\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}})}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$.
Questions
What can we say about the categorical properties of $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ based on the categorical properties of $\mathcal{A}$? For example, when is $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ complete or cocomplete? What can we say about the categorical properties of $I$? In particular, is $I$ fully faithful?
Is $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ in some sense a completion of $\mathcal{A}$? In particular, is the functor $I: \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}} \to \widehat{(\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}})}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ an equivalence of categories?
Does the construction of $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{B}}}$ from $\mathcal{A}$ have a common name? Can you give any reference?
Motivation
This is all inspired by the way the category of Frölicher spaces is constructed: We take triples $(B, T_B, F_B)$, where $B$ is some set, $T_B$ is a collection of set mappings $\mathbb{R} \to B$ and $F_B$ is a collection of set mappings $B \to \mathbb{R}$. We declare $T_B$ to be $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}, B)$ and $F_B$ to be $C^\infty(B, \mathbb{R})$, requiring compatibility conditions on them that are essentially (1.) and (2.). This essentially corresponds to taking $\mathcal{A} = C^\infty\mathsf{-Man}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \mathsf{Set}$.
It is also similar to the way maximal differentiable atlases on topological manifolds are defined: We take a topological space $B$ of dimension $n$. Then, we take a maximal collection $\mathcal{U} = \{(U, \varphi_U)\}$ where the $U \subseteq B$ are open subsets of $B$ and the $\varphi_U$ are homeomorphisms between $U$ and some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We declare all the $\varphi_U$ to be differentiable and then require a compatibility condition on the $\varphi_U$. This means that $\mathcal{U}$ takes both the role of the $T_B$ and the $F_B$. This essentially corresponds to taking $\mathcal{A} = C^\infty\mathsf{-Man}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \mathsf{Top}$.

To clarify, the functor $I$ is at least intuitively supposed to be an "embedding" of the original category inside of the new category? The definitions of $T_B$ and $F_B$ look vaguely like adjuncts (or equivalence classes of something that looks vaguely like adjuncts) so possibly there is an adjunction involved here? At the risk of being overly lazy / stupid, given that we have something that looks like it's both related to adjunctions and possibly involving an embedding, then are we sure this construction isn't equivalent to the Yoneda embedding? (We're even discussing functors $\to Set$.)

You mention Frolicher spaces -- I can not claim to understand even 10% of this meaningfully, but are you aware of diffeological spaces? E.g. compare remark 4.7 of the nLab article mentioning Frolicher spaces https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diffeological+space#EmbeddingOfSmoothManifoldsIntoDiffeoloticalSpaces is the construction you are giving not related to the embeddings discussed in that section? Possibly this review is relevant / helpful https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04576.pdf although the only embedding it mentions involves Mostow spaces which are probably unrelated...

@⁨Chill2Macht
Yes, the functor $I: \mathcal{A} \to \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{{\mathcal{B}}}$ is supposed to be an embedding of $\mathcal{A}$ into $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{{\mathcal{B}}}$. I'm pretty sure that $I$ is always faithful, but I'm not sure whether it's fully faithful.
I think that this is different from the Yoneda embedding. The Yoneda embedding simply requires that the hom-sets of your category be proper sets, but in this case, we need to start from a given faithful functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set}$ and not every category even admits a faithful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$.

I think the following should also hold: If we have categories $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$, a fully faithful functor $I: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ and a faithful functor $F: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}$, then the completion $\widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{{\mathcal{C}}}$ given via $F \circ I$ has the property that the faithful functor $J: \mathcal{A} \to \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{{\mathcal{C}}}$ factors through $I$, meaning that there is a faithful functor $K: \mathcal{B} \to \widehat{\mathcal{A}}^{_{\mathcal{C}}}$ with $J = K \circ I$.
...

...
As an example, consider $\mathcal{A} = \mathsf{AbGrp}$, $\mathcal{B} = \mathsf{Grp}$ and $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{Set}$.

I find this question interesting but admittedly I have no clue what the answer is. To be honest it seems like it could be a problem that no one else has thought about before, hence research-level, so you could possibly considering asking it or a similar question on MathOverflow. Or even writing a research preprint (I do not know what the preferences of category-theoretic journals are however and whether any would be interested in this research topic -- academia tends to be hierarchical and cliquey, and which results are "important" are largely a matter of aesthetics / taste rather than fact.)
